# updateTabsetPanel now, without delay

Tags: r, shiny

In the following minimal example, note that while the `file.choose()` line is commented out, the code works as expected: clicking the OK button on the *Input* tab switches to the *Results* tab.

However, uncomment the `file.choose()` line and the `updateTabsetPanel()` function no longer works. Is there some way to get the tab to change on the screen before the `file.choose()` begins?

```
ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
         tabsetPanel(id="main",
            tabPanel("Input", actionButton("okButton", "OK")),
            tabPanel("Results", h3(textOutput("results")))
         )))

server <-function(input, output, session) {

   output$results = renderText("Results Tab")

   observeEvent(input$okButton, {
      updateTabsetPanel(session, "main", "Results")
   #   file.choose()
   })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps: 1. Switch the tab; 2. Based on the tab switching event, open the file choose window.

```
ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(
  tabsetPanel(id="main",
              tabPanel("Input", actionButton("okButton", "OK")),
              tabPanel("Results", h3(textOutput("results")))
  )))

server <-function(input, output, session) {

  output$results = renderText("Results Tab")

  observeEvent(input$okButton, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "main", "Results")
  })

  observeEvent(input$main, {
    if (input$main == "Results") {
      file.choose()
    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That does work great for this minimal example, but in the larger project I'm already observing tab menu events and using them for something else. I suppose I could set a flag of some kind in this event that would trip in those events, but I was really hoping for some kind of command to put in between the updateTabsetPanel() and the file.choose() that told Shiny I'd wait for here it to clear its pending tasks. (In the real app, there's a long task with several progress bars after the file.choose())

Comment: That does not seem to be possible. When you put multiple commands in a reactive command, the results always return the same time, with the exception that you use Javascript or call another R process in the middle.

Comment: On further thought, your solution is really the only possibility. Otherwise the updateTabsetPanel() will start up a different observeEvent() (for the tab) while I'm still in the middle of this one. Thanks for helping me think this through. I think I'll just save all the data I need on the first observeEvent() and have a different observeEvent() button that initiates all the processing based on the saved data.